# Where is the object of ExploreModel created?

Tags: kotlin

The following code is the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

I don't understand fully the code `onExploreItemClicked = { launchDetailsActivity(context = this, item = it) }` in `class MainActivity` .

The fun `launchDetailsActivity` requires two paramaters which are `Context` and `ExploreModel`.

One of paramater is `Context` which is assigned with `this`, it's OK;

Another of paramater is `ExploreMode`l which is assigned with `it`, I don't know where the object `ExploreModel` which is represented with `it` is created, could you tell me?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            ProvideWindowInsets {
                ProvideImageLoader {
                    CraneTheme {
                        MainScreen(
                            onExploreItemClicked = { launchDetailsActivity(context = this, item = it) }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MainScreen(onExploreItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked) {
   ...
}


typealias OnExploreItemClicked = (ExploreModel) -> Unit


fun launchDetailsActivity(context: Context, item: ExploreModel) {
    context.startActivity(createDetailsActivityIntent(context, item))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for `onExploreItemClicked` is an implementation of `(ExploreModel) -> Unit`. That function type is created via a lambda expression. In Kotlin, if a lambda has only one parameter then that parameter can be omitted and it's given the implicit name of `it`.

So in this case, `it` is the `ExploreModel` instance passed to the function when invoked. Which instance that will be is likely dependent on which "explore item" is clicked on the screen. I haven't properly read all the code, but I did find this in [ExploreSection.kt](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab/app/src/main/java/androidx/compose/samples/crane/base/ExploreSection.kt#L105) (by following the code starting with the construction of `MainScreen`):

> ```kotlin
> @OptIn(ExperimentalCoilApi::class) 
> @Composable 
> private fun ExploreItem(
>     modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
>     item: ExploreModel,
>     onItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked ) {
>     Row(
>         modifier = modifier
>             .clickable { onItemClicked(item) }
>             .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp)
>     ) { 
>
> /* REST OMITTED FOR BREVITY */
> ```

It accepts the `OnExploreItemClicked` instance, as well as an `ExploreModel` instance. Then, in the `clickable` labmda, it invokes the `OnExploreItemClicked` function:

> ```kotlin
> .clickable { onItemClicked(item) }
> ```

And it passes in the associated `ExploreModel` instance. Of course, that only tells you where `it` (that we previously talked about) gets its value, but it doesn't tell you where the `ExploreModel` instance is actually created. You'd have to explore the code more to see where `ExploreItem` is called, and where it gets the model (I believe it at least comes from the view model).

---

Note if you don't want to use the implicit `it`, then you can give the parameter an explicit name (and type, if wanted). For example:

```kotlin
MainScreen(
    onExploreItemClicked = { model: ExploreModel -> launchDetailsActivity(context = this, item = model) }
)
```

---

Further reading:

- [Function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types)
- [Lambda expressions and anonymous functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions)

  - [it: implicit name of a single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter)